# Angular - add dynamically created FormControls into the FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a list, simple - `string[]`. I generate checkbox for every item of that list. Then I create FormControls:

```
this.list.map((item) => {
  this.form.addControl(item, new FormControl(false, Validators.required))
})
```

But I want to add a `Validator` to control the allowed number of checked checkboxes, so I assume I could do this if I move those `FormControls` into the `FormGroup`, so I try something like:

```
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { 
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          input1Ctrl: ['', Validators.required],
          input2Ctrl: ['',Validators.required],
          checkboxGroup : new FormGroup({})   
        })         
        this.list.map((item) => {
          this.form.checkboxGroup.addControl(item, new FormControl(false, Validators.required))
        })
```

But that gives:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>   Property 'checkboxGroup' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

How should I do it?

Comment: Why `this.form.checkboxGroup`? That is perfectly invalid. And that is why you have the error.

Comment: `this.form.get('checkboxGroup').addControl(...)`

Comment: Thanks @developer033, But now I get -  Property 'addControl' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'... Thats strange, because I provided the `FormGroup` type for `checkboxGroup`...

Comment: @user8558489 `(this.form.get('checkboxGroup') as FormGroup).addControl(...)`

Comment: @user8558489 - Perfect (just had to store `(this.form.get('checkboxGroup') as FormGroup` in local variable and then `addControl`. Feel free to post an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Access `checkboxGroup` like `this.form.controls['checkboxGroup']`.

```
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { 
            this.form = this.fb.group({
              input1Ctrl: ['', Validators.required],
              input2Ctrl: ['',Validators.required],
              checkboxGroup : new FormGroup({})   
            })         
            this.list.map((item) => {
              this.form.controls['checkboxGroup'].addControl(item, new FormControl(false, Validators.required))
            })
```

**EDIT** : Created plunker for the above

https://plnkr.co/edit/nxo52y?p=preview

Comment: The same as when using the dot

Comment: @user8558489 I have created a plunker. You can check the console. No issues with it. It just works fine.

Comment: Youre using `FormGroup` here not formBuilder's `fb.formGroup` so yes it is different. See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#control

Answer (score 0):

You're using `FormGroup` here not formBuilder's `group` method.

It seems you would set it up like:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
   checkboxGroup: this.fb.group({})
})
```

Accessing FormBuilder's `group` and `FormGroup` both work for me like:
`this.form.get('checkboxGroup')` 
and 
`this.form.controls['checkboxGroup']

See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#control